# Is there a connection between Shared element transition and the app Theme?

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have a program that i made in android studio which uses shared element transition, the problem is that i have a title bar that i want to remove and when i remove it for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

the shared element transition stop working, and when i return to the old theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

the shared element transition start working again.

why there's a connection between those features and how can i fix this problem?
Thank you all.

for sdk version:
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are various settings within a theme that affect shared element transitions. Most of them contain the word `windowSharedElement<something>`